# Parse pandas column names to create multi-indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, multi-index

I've got a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
region   2008_indicatorA   2008_indicatorB  ...(2009..2019)...  2020_indicatorA   2020_indicatorB
=============================================================================================
State1   ...               ...              ...                 ...
State2   ...               ...              ...                 ...
...
```

I need to extract the years from the columns and make a separate column `year`, at the same time reducing the number of columns. The resulting DF should look like this:

```
region   year   indicatorA   indicatorB
========================================
State1   2008   ...          ...
State1   2009   ...          ...
...
State1  (..2020) ...         ...
...
State2   2008   ...          ...
...
```

I am sure this transformation has something to do with [reindex()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) or [unstack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) or [stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)... But completely don't know how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with `split` for `MultiIndex in columns` and then [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) with reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
print (df)
   region  2008_indicatorA  2008_indicatorB  2020_indicatorA  2020_indicatorB
0  State1                1                3                5                8
1  State2                7                5                3                9

df1 = df.set_index('region')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.rename_axis(['year',None], axis=1).stack(0).reset_index()
print (df1)
   region  year  indicatorA  indicatorB
0  State1  2008           1           3
1  State1  2020           5           8
2  State2  2008           7           5
3  State2  2020           3           9
```

For `MultiIndex DataFrame` remove [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index('region')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df1 = df1.rename_axis(['year',None], axis=1).stack(0)
print (df1)
             indicatorA  indicatorB
region year                        
State1 2008           1           3
       2020           5           8
State2 2008           7           5
       2020           3           9
```